# I can't get ListView background image drawn

Tags: c#, listview, background

So I'm using the design view and I set my ListView's background image, however it is not drawing when I debug it. It is however drawn on the design view. I can change the background colour ( this has no effect in design view, but in debug it changes background colour )

Put simply: My background image is not drawn.

Comment: So your listview's background image is not rendering while debugging? however it works fine on design and runtime (without debugging), right?

Comment: No, it doesn't work at all, Only in design view when in Visual Studio

Comment: I debugged it a bit, It is not about the variables, I created a new project with just the list view with background. It worked but when I tried to do the same by setting variables to exactly same in my listview I'm trying to use it failed. I think it's a bug hidden somewhere in the design system

Comment: Turns out it has something to do with my project in general, not just the forms or listviews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found out if you're not running in STA Mode it wont draw the image